# Blackberry: BrowserField2 API scrolling issue on OS 5.0

Tags: java, blackberry

I have  strange issue with browseField2 API on device 9700 (BB OS 5.0).

Browser field is displays blank white space exactly of screen height after rendering HTML content of the browser field. I have added browser field on VerticalFieldManager  and this manager also has other controls on it. I also tried with directly adding browse field on screen in combination of other controls on screen, but it doesn’t worked.  My goal is to add browser field on screen which has others controls added on it. Also scrolling between controls should be proper.

Here is code snippet which I am using –

BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();                                  myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);

```
  myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);

  browseField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);     

  LOMABrowseField2Listener listener = new LOMABrowseField2Listener();

  ProtocolController protocolController = new ProtocolController(browseField);

  myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, protocolController);

  String myProtocol = "http";

  protocolController.setNavigationRequestHandler(myProtocol, listener);

  browseField.displayContent(htmlSpecificContent,"");
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. This was not the issue with browser field instead the screen which has the browser field was vertically scrollable. The fix is the screen should be vertically non scrollable.